# SNOWFLAKE Data not showing, stored as NULL but display the data

Tags: snowflake-stage

I am facing weird issue. We have sent data from ServiceNow to SNOWFLAKE on some table.

The table shows the values in column in SNOWFLAKE but when trying to fetch by adding WHERE clause on different columns e.g. number, created date, it shows no results and these records are getting fetched only when I am searching with NULL

The syntax is correct.

```
SELECT * from PROD_STAGING.SERVICENOW.ASMT_METRIC_RESULT WHERE assign_to_order LIKE '%SANDY%'
```

shows no results. But I can see the data in SNOWFLAKE.

```
SELECT * from PROD_STAGING.SERVICENOW.ASMT_METRIC_RESULT WHERE assign_to_order is NULL
```

showing the value.

Again to mention, I do see the data in table.

Didn't find any supporting document.

Comment: Hi - please can you update your question with a screenshot of the query that is returning data and some of the records that it’s producing - including the assign_to_order column